# Safari animation not working on any Apple device

Tags: ios, safari, css-animations

Basically what it does is just slide left without the fade in and out happening. Not sure why this is happening. The CSS code is below.

I have the keyframes:

```
@-webkit-keyframes heroTitleMove {
0% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left:0;
}
25% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left:0;
}
31.25% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
32.25% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -700%
}

    38.5% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: -700%;
}
    63.5% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: -700%;
}
69.75% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -700%;
}
70.75% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -1400%
}
    77% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: -1400%;
}
}
@-moz-keyframes heroTitleMove {
0% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left:0;
}
25% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left:0;
}
31.25% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
32.25% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -700%
}

    38.5% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: -700%;
}
    63.5% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: -700%;
}
69.75% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -700%;
}
70.75% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -1400%
}
    77% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: -1400%;
}
}
@-o-keyframes heroTitleMove {
0% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left:0;
}
25% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left:0;
}
31.25% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
32.25% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -700%
}

    38.5% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: -700%;
}
    63.5% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: -700%;
}
69.75% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -700%;
}
70.75% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -1400%
}
    77% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: -1400%;
}
}
@keyframes heroTitleMove {
0% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left:0;
}
25% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left:0;
}
31.25% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
32.25% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -700%
}

    38.5% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: -700%;
}
    63.5% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: -700%;
}
69.75% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -700%;
}
70.75% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -1400%
}
    77% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: -1400%;
}
}
```

Then I have the CSS:

```
.hero-title {
    margin-left: -1400%;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: heroTitleMove 16s;
    -moz-animation:    heroTitleMove 16s;
    -o-animation:      heroTitleMove 16s;
    animation: heroTitleMove 16s;
}
```

The fade out and in doesn't seem to work on Safari. It will work on every other browser.

Please help.

**JSFIDDLE:**

https://jsfiddle.net/9u7b1tkf/

Comment: Please add a starting point in code (for example CodePen or JSFiddle).

Comment: Does it work on Safari desktop?

Comment: I dont believe so. either.

Comment: Also I have attached the jsfiddle